# function as templated parameter in cuda

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, parameter-passing

I'm attempting to write a reduction function in cuda (this is an exercise, I know that I'm doing things which have been done better by other people) which takes a binary associative operator and an array and reduces the array using the operator.

I'm having difficulty with how to pass the function. I've written hostOp() as a host based example which works fine.

deviceOp() works for the first statement with an explicit call to fminf(), but when I call the function parameter, there is an illegal memory access error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; //for brevity

__device__  float g_d_a = 9, g_d_b = 5;
float g_h_a = 9, g_h_b = 5;

template<typename argT, typename funcT>
__global__
void deviceOp(funcT op){    
    argT result = fminf(g_d_a, g_d_b);                  //works fine
    printf("static function result: %f\n", result);
    result = op(g_d_a,g_d_b);                           //illegal memory access
    printf("template function result: %f\n", result);
}

template<typename argT, typename funcT>                 
void hostOp(funcT op){
    argT result = op(g_h_a, g_h_b);
    printf("template function result: %f\n", result);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    hostOp<float>(min<float>);                          //works fine
    deviceOp<float><<<1,1>>>(fminf);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); 
    cout<<cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError())<<endl;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
host function result: 5.000000
static function result: 5.000000
an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Assuming I'm not doing something horribly stupid, how should I be passing fminf to deviceOp so that there isn't an illegal memory access?

If I am doing something horribly stupid, what is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function to be called on the device must be decorated with `__device__` (or `__global__`, if you wish it to be a kernel).  The `nvcc` compiler driver will then separate host and device code, and will use the device-compiled version of the function when it is called from (i.e. compiled in) device code, and the host version otherwise.

This construct is problematic:

```
deviceOp<float><<<1,1>>>(fminf);
```

While it may not be obvious, this is essentially all host code.  Yes, it is launching a kernel (via an underlying sequence of library calls from host code), but it is technically host code. Therefore the `fminf` function address "captured" here will be the *host* version of the `fminf` function, even though a device version is available (via CUDA `math.h`, which you are not actually including).

A typical albeit clumsy approach to work around this is to "capture" the device address *in device code*, then pass it as a parameter to your kernel.

You can also short-circuit this process (somewhat) if you are passing function addresses that can be deduced at compile time, with a slightly different templating technique.  These concepts are covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879789/thrust-transform-throws-error-bulk-kernel-by-value-an-illegal-memory-access-w/34880426#34880426).

Here is a fully worked example of your code modified using the "capture function address in device code" method:

```
$ cat t1176.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; //for brevity

__device__  float g_d_a = 9, g_d_b = 5;
float g_h_a = 9, g_h_b = 5;

template<typename argT, typename funcT>
__global__
void deviceOp(funcT op){
    argT result = fminf(g_d_a, g_d_b);                  //works fine
    printf("static function result: %f\n", result);
    result = op(g_d_a,g_d_b);                           //illegal memory access
    printf("template function result: %f\n", result);
}

__device__ float (*my_fminf)(float, float) = fminf;  // "capture" device function address

template<typename argT, typename funcT>
void hostOp(funcT op){
    argT result = op(g_h_a, g_h_b);
    printf("template function result: %f\n", result);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    hostOp<float>(min<float>);                          //works fine
    float (*h_fminf)(float, float);
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_fminf, my_fminf, sizeof(void *));
    deviceOp<float><<<1,1>>>(h_fminf);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cout<<cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError())<<endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1176 t1176.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1176
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
template function result: 5.000000
static function result: 5.000000
template function result: 5.000000
no error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Hm. So when I call deviceOp from the host, it is called as device code, but if I were to call it from the device, it would be device code (and would know where fminf is as it apparently does?)

Comment: `deviceOp` is a `__global__` function.  It is not actually called from the host (in the way that an ordinary host function would be called from host code) but is actually a kernel launch (which is accomplished via a sequence of library calls - to launch the function on the device.)  If you did launch `deviceOp` from device code (i.e. dynamic parallelism, then that particular kernel launch from device code would be able to pick up the device fminf function address directly - and in fact the kernel launch itself would be compiled as device code.

Comment: The direct `fminf` call that is explicit in `deviceOp` is in fact device code.  Anything within the `__global__` or `__device__` function scope qualifers is device code, and is compiled by the device code compiler.  But the **launch** of `deviceOp` from your `main` routine is actually all host code.